# CSS Fixed width right, fluid left, right div is first in html. How do I keep left from collapsing

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a fluid-width left div and a fixed-width right div.
It took a while to figure out how to make this work because I am theming a jrox site and jrox will not let me change the order the columns are generated. 
The HTML:

```
<div id="jroxHeader" class="jroxHeader"> </div>
<div id="jroxContent">
    <div id="jroxRightColumn" class="jroxRightColumn"> Places to go:
      <ul>
        <li>First Menu</li>
        <li>Second Menu</li>
        <li>Third Menu</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="jroxMainContent" class="jroxSingleColumn">  
        Very little content.
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.jroxSingleColumn{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#B6B6B4;
}
.jroxRightColumn{
  float: right;
  width: 160px; 
  margin-left: -160px; 
  background-color:#8E8E8C;
}
.jroxHeader{
   width: 100%;
   background-color:#7A7A78;
   height:150px;
}
```

As you can see with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/19/) this looks great. It works almost perfectly. I didn't notice and issue until I came across a page with very little content in the jroxSingleColumn like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/18/). I need the jroxSingleColumn to fill the remaining part of the div and I need it to be cross browser compatible. I can change some of the HTML but the right column will always be in HTML first.

I am almost positive this is not a duplicate. I have read many **many** similar problems but none are the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `float:left` from your `jroxSingleColumn` class i.e

change your css to this:

```
.jroxSingleColumn{
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#B6B6B4;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/21/)

Though I would like to suggest, there are much cleaner ways of achieving your end result.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question. Your answer is absolutely correct for the question. The real question should have been using [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/24/) fiddle but when creating the fiddle I rewrote the shorter version of the page and I rewrote it in the wrong order. How should I go about getting an answer without any down-votes on this one? Should I: Re-ask the question correctly? Edit this question? Give up on S/O and figure it out myself?

Comment: haha, not a problem mate, you can always ask your doubts back. for better response, you can put it into a new question, only rule is, you should have paid your effort to it :). Now, see, since you cannot change the markup, there is not much that can be done, what best i can suggest you to go for simple jQuery code, that would handle resize of your left div. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/29/). Why a script? your markup is not exactly fluid, hence we are left with almost no other option :)

Comment: I do like the jQuery fix but I have since reposted the question with the correct wording [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932960) and I think I found a good solution. Thanks.