# CSS (Fixed width right, fluid left, left is first in html) How do I keep left div from collapsing?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I have a fluid-width left div and a fixed-width right div. It took a while to figure out how to make this work because I am theming a jrox site and jrox will not let me change the order the columns are generated. The HTML:

```
<div id="jroxHeader" class="jroxHeader"> </div>
<div id="jroxContent">
  <div id="jroxMainContent" class="jroxSingleColumn">  
    Very little content.
  </div>
  <div id="jroxRightColumn" class="jroxRightColumn"> Places to go:
    <ul>
      <li>First Menu</li>
      <li>Second Menu</li>
      <li>Third Menu</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.jroxSingleColumn{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#B6B6B4;
}
.jroxRightColumn{
  float: right;
  width: 160px; 
  margin-left: -160px; 
  background-color:#8E8E8C;
}
.jroxHeader{
   width: 100%;
   background-color:#7A7A78;
   height:150px;
}
```

As you can see with [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/25/) fiddle the above looks great. It works almost perfectly. I didn't notice any issue until I came across a page with very little content in the jroxSingleColumn like in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/24/) fiddle. I need the jroxSingleColumn to fill the remaining part of the div and I need it to be cross browser compatible. I can change some of the HTML but the left column (jroxSingleColumn) will always be in HTML first.

I am almost positive this is not a duplicate. I have read many many similar problems but none are the same.

Thanks.

**----- Notice: -----**

The other day I asked this same question but I had the HTML code wrong. I looked all over stackoverflow.com to find the correct way to go about fixing my mistake and I found nothing on what to do in this situation. I believe I have done the right thing by accepting the correct answer to my incorrectly asked question and re-asking the question with the correct wording. The incorrect question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868969). That fix will not work with the HTML in the correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a variation using a mix of `relative` and `absolute` positioning.  Though I like the display table and table-cell option.

Remove the floats, apply `position: relative;` to `#jroxContent` and `position: absolute;` to `.jroxRightColumn`.  After that simply move `.jroxRightColumn` to the top right with `top: 0; right: 0;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/28/

*CSS*

```css
#jroxContent{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
}
.jroxSingleColumn{
     margin-right: 160px;
     padding:0 10px;
     width:auto;
     background-color:#B6B6B4;
}
.jroxRightColumn{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 160px;  
     background-color:#8E8E8C;
}
.jroxHeader{
     width: 100%;
     background-color:#7A7A78;
     height:150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:table` for the parent container and `display:table-cell` for the two columns within. The one first in the DOM will be to the left and the next will be to the right. Set fixed width for whichever you want to , and auto width for the other and it will fill up remaining space.

Here's a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ZVP6A/26/

Comment: I may go with something like this but I would like it to be supported by IE7 and up without messing with too much [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is remove `float: left;` from the left column. Put this column markup below the right column, Assign overflow hidden, and it will work perfectly.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/ZVP6A/27/

```
.jroxSingleColumn{
  margin-right: 160px;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color:#B6B6B4;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: OP said the left column will always be first and they cannot adjust this.

Comment: Though your answer would be my preference if one could switch the markup.